"Autocorrect format" for all values in a column (instead of line by line)
[In Excel 2016] I received worksheets with dates arranged like MM/DD/YYYY, but I need it in YYYY/MM/DD order. I use formulas to rearrange them into the correct order in a string, then paste all as values.
Original date on left, calculated date on right

However, after pasting as values, excel doesn't seem to to actually recognize the final result as a date, unless I go line by line.
1st row: Result after manually "opening and closing" the cell data. 2nd row: Manually editing the data. 3rd row: Value still in previous format.

I was going to design a macro to do this, but when I record the macro to see what the action is, it doesn't show any steps apart from "selecting" the cell.
I've tried changing the formats from General to Text to Date and every which way, but nothing seems to work apart from line by line. Would greatly appreciate some help in understanding what I'm missing (and also if I'm in the right place)!
I found a couple other questions close to mine, but they seemed to refer to converting using specific coding methods (i.e. pandas python) which is a bit beyond my requirements.

Steps to reproduce:

Rearrange date values using a formula.
Paste calculated values as values only.

What I expected to happen: Values would automatically "auto-detect" the format for the entire column.
What happened: Values remain as as basic text string (instead of changing to excel date values), and only update after manually opening and closing each cell.

What formula did you use?

You should just be able to format the cells as you would like.

@ScottCraner Thanks for replying -- I removed the formula to paste the values, so the issue I'm having is formatting the values themselves. The formula to rearrange MM/DD/YYYY, to YYYY/MM/DD is: =RIGHT([@OrigDate],4)&"/"&LEFT([@OrigDate],5)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try this method:
Open the file contains your data (the same file mentioned in your question)
From the Data Ribbon select:
New Query>From File>From Workbook
Now select the same file you opened already
From the dialouge box select the sheet which contains the dates, then Press Load
New worksheet will created, with table contains values with correct date.
In the same created sheet:
Choose Column A
Go to the Design Ribbon
Press the Button: Convert to Range
Confirm the process by choosing Ok from the popup message.

This addressed my issue, thank you so much!! I did not think to re-load the same table as a data query, though it really does seem like there should be a more intuitive method to accomplishing this? // NOTE: To save a step, I was able to just copy the new worksheet's columns into the old table (which pasted correctly), then delete the new worksheet and related query.
